# Using Unity 2.0 handle exception

Tags: unity-container, aop

When I use Unity 2.0 to handle exception, I got some problem, like below:

```
public class TraceBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke method:{0}",input.MethodBase.ToString()));
        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        if (result.Exception == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoke successful!");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke faild, error: {0}", result.Exception.Message));
            result.Exception = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool WillExecute { get { return true; } }
}
```

I have set result.Exception=null (it's meaning that I have resolved the exception and need not throw again.)
However,it throw a exception to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how it works. Don't set result.Exception, instead return input.CreateMethodReturn(newReturnValues).

Comment: Thank you very much. But "input.CreateMethodReturn(newReturnValues)" is not valid, I did not find type-newReturnValues.

Comment: That's not a type, it was just me sticking in a value. Put your return value here. If it's a void method being intercepted, put null in there.

Comment: newReturnValues represents the return value of the function. Assuming getNext() threw an exception and you don't want to re-throw it, you will have to return _some_ value from the function.

Comment: @ChrisTavares thanks a ton for this answer. So know, problem is if the return type is a primitive (`ByVal`) type, I can't return `null` If I do that, it causes another exception when it returns. Is there a way around this or a way I can figure if the return **type** is `ByVal`?

Comment: If it's a value type, pick a return value. return 0, or -1, or 6.02e23. It's up to you, and what's a reasonable response based on your interception behavior and it's intended purpose. You can use the reflection APIs to figure out what the return type is and the potential valid values to return (default<T> is often a good choice as well).